# improve https redirect loading time

Tags: wordpress, redirect, https

I am the co-webmaster of the site www.accademiadellevante.org and recently we have made a restyling of the site and change from http to https.

After the migration we noticed that the loading time of the site by accessing directly to www.accademiadellevante.org (therefore http) is slow redirect (redirect 301 on the htaccess file) to the https page. If access is made directly in https (by typing in the address bar https://www.accademiadellevante.org) you will earn about 4s on the loading time.

The site is based on Wordpress and the Really Simple SSL plugin is installed. In the database the links are always in http.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you retain `http` links in the database when you could update them very easily to `https`?

Answer (score 0):

on the webhosting provider cpanel or whm, there is redirect section, you can put your redirects there, it will be much faster.